# Selenium TestNG Test running order

Tags: selenium, testng, pom.xml

I'm following page object model for my application's testing. Below are the tests I've written.

1. loginTest (validLogin(), invalidLogin())
2. addTeacherTest (validAddTeacher(), invalidAddTeacher())
3. logoutTest (logout())

Business flows to be tested are like-

1. validLogin() -> validAddTeacher() -> Logout
2. validLogin() -> invalidAddTeacher()

Now, i want to parameterize complete flow and not indiviual tests, using TestNG.xml. Can I do that? If not, then how can I test complete business flow in Selenium/PoM?

Comment: Is it like, You want to run specific set of test cases based on some parameter which you pass from testNG xml?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a situation where tests are dependent on other tests, why not offload these functional methods to another class and simply call them in the desired order from `@Test` methods?  This way, you'd still be able to easily run tests in parallel and you would alleviate the test-dependency issue.  Additionally, parametrization becomes simple with this approach.  You'd need only add your desired `<parameter>` tags inside each `<test>` tag on your testng.xml file.